# Find and classify isolated singularities of $f(z) = \frac{z}{1-e^{z^2}}$ and calculate residues on them

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, laurent-series

Obviously, all isolated singularities will be of the form $z=\sqrt{2 \pi i k}$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ but I don't know how to classify. I tried expanding $\frac{1}{f} = \frac{1-e^{z^2}}{z}$ to $- \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^{2n -1}}{n!}$ which is of the form $zg(z)$ where $g$ is analytic near $0$ and $g(0) \neq 0$ so I can say $0$ is a simple zero of $\frac{1-e^{z^2}}{z}$ hence a simple pole of $\frac{z}{1-e^{z^2}}$. But how do I generalize?

Comment: in general the quotient $ h(z) =\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}$ of two entire functions is [meromorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meromorphic_function) : i.e. its singularities are poles. the proof is the same as what you wrote : $h(z)$ is analytic where $g(z) \ne 0$, and if $a$ is zero : $ \ \ g(z) = C (z-a)^k g_a(z)$ where $g_a(z) = \frac{g(z)}{C (z-a)^k}$ is analytic at $z=a$ and $g_a(a) = 1$.  for the residue, you have to find the few first terms of the Laurent series, and keep the coef $c_{-1}$  (when the pole is of order $1$, it reduces to finding the $C$ I mentioned )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For zero:

$$f(z)=\frac z{-z^2-\frac{z^4}{2!}+-\ldots}=-\frac1{z+\frac{z^3}2+\ldots}=-\frac1{z\left(1+\frac{z^2}2+\ldots\right)}=$$

$$=-\frac1z\left(1-\left(1+\frac{z^2}2+\ldots\right)+\left(1+\frac{z^2}2+\ldots\right)^2\right)-\ldots\implies z=0$$

is at most a simple pole, but since $\;\lim\limits_{z\to0}f(z)\;$ isn't finite then *it is* a simple pole, and it's residue is

$$\lim_{z\to0}z(f(z))\stackrel{\text{l'Hospital}}=\lim_{z\to0}\frac{2z}{-2ze^{z^2}}=-1$$

at $\;z=z_k:=\sqrt{2k\pi i}\;$: choosing the branch of the square root for which $\;\sqrt1=1\;$ , we get:

$$\lim_{z\to z_k}(z-z_k)f(z)\stackrel{\text{l'H}}=\lim_{z\to z_k}\frac{z+z-z_k}{-2ze^{z^2}}=\frac{z_k}{-2z_ke^{z_k^2}}=-\frac12$$